# Move items on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 4 elements, which ordered as 1,2,3,4.
I can change this order by dragging and dropping the elements. The thing is, I want the elements to change on all browsers that are on that page. At the moment I’ve made a working ajax call and I’m able get this data in other browsers.

Now my problem: with the data that I receive from the ajax call, I want to update the items which are have wrong order.

Example of changed data:

```
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  order: 3
},
{
  id: 2,
  order: 1
}];
```

Inside my html I have an attribute called ‘data-board-id’, and ‘data-order’. These are referring to the order and the board ID.

Comment: Can you be more informative, how your html structure is, are you using jquery/pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try using [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

I hope this answers your very vague question

Comment: I've added more info maybe you understand the question better and can you reply!

Answer (score 0):

Upon receiving the data from your Ajax request, you can use the order-id to as keys to create an ordered array. For example;

```
var items = [];
items[data-order] = id; // items[1] = 3 & items[2] = 1;
```

Loop over the items array replace the divs as necessary. I would even consider wiping the data-board clean and adding them from scratch within the loop.

The code above won't solve this issue, but might help you get it moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad question! I have taken some screenshots from my HTML.
I have two Google Chrome tabs open which every 3 seconds receives an ajax call with data like so: http://puu.sh/nAsXy/646d24dcdb.png.

If you compare the images below you can see that I want to change the HTML list with the correct order if any changes are made.

Screenshot of the current HTML:
http: //puu.sh/nAsGx/6fdc334e45.png

Screenshot of the changed HTML in first Google Chrome tab: http: //puu.sh/nAsIz/bea08f029d.png

Screenshot of second Google Chrome tab after ajax call: http: //puu.sh/nAsNK/b3993e8ae9.png

I can't post more than two links because of my reputation...